# how to redirect 301 my old search query string to wordpress search query string?

Tags: htaccess

How to redirect 301:

```
/cgi-bin/mt/mt-search.cgi?search=WORDS
```

to

```
https://example.com/?s=WORDS
```

in `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file (*before* the WordPress block):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/mt/mt-search\.cgi$ /?s=%1 [R=301,L]
```

`%1` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is a backreference to the captured group in the preceding *CondPattern* (ie. the value of the *search* URL parameter - "WORDS").

Clear your browser cache before testing.

It is preferable to first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html